# Find the number of pairs of (i, j) such that i < j and Ai + Aj = 2^x where x is an integer. In java

Tags: java, algorithm, math, logic

You are given an array A of length N. Find the number of pairs of (i, j) such that i < j and A<sub>i</sub> + A<sub>j</sub> = 2<sup>x</sup> where x is an integer. Since the answer could be large return it modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7.

###### Function description

Complete the twiceMatch function in the editor below. It has the following parameter(s):

| Name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | INTEGER ARRAY | array of non-negative integers. |

###### Return

The function must return an INTEGER denoting the number of ordered pairs satisfying the condition.
Constraints

- 1  ≤ N ≤  10<sup>5</sup>
- 1  ≤ A<sub>i</sub> ≤  10<sup>9</sup>

###### Examples, first number in the input is the number of array values to follow

| Input | Output | Output Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 1 15 2 7 | 2 | ordered pairs of indices satisfying the conditions are: (1, 2), (1, 4) |
| 5 1 2 3 4 5 | 2 | ordered pairs of indices satisfying the conditions are: (1, 3), (3, 5) |
| 5 2 2 2 2 2 | 10 | All pairs of (i, j) satisfies the condition. |

Out of 15 Test cases only 1 is fails. The testcase is hidden.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Solution {
    public static int twiceMatch(int[] A) {
        int n = A.length;
        int mod = (int)(1e9 + 9);

        Map <Integer, Integer> freqMap = new HashMap < >();

        for (int num: A) {
            freqMap.put(num, freqMap.getOrDefault(num, 0) + 1);
        }

        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= 30; x++) {
                int target = (1 << x) - A[i];
                if (target < 0)
                    continue;

                if (freqMap.containsKey(target)) {
                    int freq = freqMap.get(target);

                    if (target == A[i]) {
                        freq--;
                    }

                    count = (count + freq) % mod;
                }
            }
        }

        if (count % 2 != 0) {
            count--;
        }

        if (count < 0) {
            count += mod;
        }

        if (count == 0) {
            return - 1;
        }

        return count / 2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System. in );
        int N;
        N = scan.nextInt();
        int[] A = new int[N];
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            A[j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        int result;
        result = twiceMatch(A);
        System.out.print(result);
        return;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: We only look at homework when you show what you have done so far. What errors? Provide code that can be copied and pasted.

Comment: this is not a homework assignment. I have added the code that i done as an image

Comment: And its not an error its just 1  test case is not passing.

Comment: So you add an image of the code, why would you expect anyone to re-type your code to test it for you? Paste it correctly - even have a button to use.

Comment: Maybe `int mod = (int) (1e9 +9);`

Comment: To clarify, in your text you wrote: "... return it modulo 10^9 + 7..." but in your code you have `int mod = (int) (1e9 + 9)`. So one of those is wrong, and if it's your code then that could be the source of error.

Comment: Please show us something showing you tried at least.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are summing the frequencies and then taking the mod of that sum, in some cases, resulting in the wrong answer.  You need to declare count as a long and just sum the frequencies. It needs to be a long so it won't overflow.  So instead of taking the remainder as you sum the frequencies, take it at the end before you return the value.  So...

- correct the mod to `(int)1e9 + 7`
- declare count as a long.
- tally the count using `count += freq`
- And return the value as `(int) ((count/2L)% mod);`. It's important to take the mod after correcting for duplicate pairs.  I.e. Take the `mod of the half` instead of `half of the mod`.

**Note:**  A long value for `count` is sufficient since the maximum pairings would occur for an array of size `100,000` containing `identical powers of 2`. The total frequencies would be `100_000`.  And since `100,000*99,999` would be `double` the total pairings (excluding the same index), `9,999,900,000` would be the product prior to reduction which easily fits into a `long`.

**And some other observations.**

Before you return the final result you do some adjusting on count. The following are not required.

- Adjusting count if odd is not required since integer division will yield the required result. `(e.g.  11/2 == 5 and 10/2 == 5)`
- Adding `mod to count if negative` is not required since count can never be negative. Once you decide to decrement `freq`, you have already determined that `freq` is positive since it has obtained a frequency count from the map.  So the least `freq` can be is `0`.  So `count` is only updated with values `>= 0` thus can never be negative.

**This may be obivious but...**

The sum of two `identical` numbers will only be a power of `2` if they are powers of `2`.

- `n + n = 2n`.  Whether `n` is composite or prime, it must only have `2` as factor(s).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk It was from an earlier analysis.  It has been fixed.  Thanks!